# Orchard 1.8 Getting 404 Not Found Error - Deployed via Web Matrix

Tags: orchardcms, webmatrix, permission-denied, file-not-found

I created an Orchard Website (Version 1.8)

It was created through WebMatrix.

Locally everything runs perfectly fine.

When I upload it to my server (Web Deploy also via WebMatrix) I get following Error Message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /
```

Orchard Error Logs:

```
2014-05-13 08:22:07,827 [23] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.UnmanagedLibraryHelper..ctor(String fileName)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper..ctor(String modulePath)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadValidLibrary(String modulePath)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder(String privateInstall)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Bytecode\ActivatorObjectsFactory.cs:line 9
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.CreateCommand() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Driver\ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.cs:line 35
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Driver\ReflectionBasedDriver.cs:line 65
   at NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Driver\SqlServerCeDriver.cs:line 35
   at Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Providers\SqlCeDataServicesProvider.cs:line 78
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 109
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 113
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:line 64
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProviderFactory.cs:line 50
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\SettingsFactory.cs:line 83
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1733
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1264
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:line 90
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:line 68
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.EnsureSession() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:line 117
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.Demand() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:line 42
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.For(Type entityType) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:line 36
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 26
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 30
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1 predicate) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 126
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 91
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1 predicate) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 60
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorManager.cs:line 57
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor() in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorManager.cs:line 30
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\ShellBuilders\ShellContextFactory.cs:line 66
at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings
```

I googled a bit and most posts suggested

```
Check Read/Write Permissions on Default .NET AppPool user for the folders "App_Data, Modules, Media, Themes".
```

I checked the permissions and set them this way.
Still get the excact same error though.

Any suggestions? Help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:
Solved it myself, see the seconds post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself.

It seems I had to add full permissions to every single folder in Orchard Root (even Core, Config, bin etc...) not only the mentioned 4 ones.

If you googled yourself and you stumble accross this try that out.

I'm currently removing some of the permissions again step-by-step to check for how long it works, and what the minimum required really is.

But thank you Hazza for your help, really appreciated that.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to verify DB connectivity.  In my case, I tried the above solutions and it still was returning the same 404 error message.  In the Orchard/App_Data/logs, it showed an error that was more related to the database, along the same lines as "Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver" in the OP error message.

I realized I hadn't set the security group permissions on the RDS instance at AWS hosting to properly allow the webserver EC2 instance access to the database.  Once I added the appropriate EC2 instance (security group the EC2 instances are part of actually, not just the machine), I was able to access the site without further issue.

The folder permissions are also critical, but if you try that and still not having luck, verify your database permissions are correct too!

Comment: and remember the connection string is in Settings.txt (got caught after switching to RDS from a local SQL). Restart the orchard App Pool if you change the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before and this fixed it for me:

- Right click on AppData and select properties
- Select the Security tab, click edit and then Add a new username
- Add "IIS AppPool\InsertAppPoolNameHere"

Comment: Added the user and granted full permission on the Folder and its Files / Subfolders... still the same error message.

Answer (score -2):

- Go to **src->Orchard.Web** Folder and right click properties and
  select security tab.
- Click on **edit -> Add -> Advanced** from the popped "Select Users or
  Groups" window.
- Then click on **Find Now** to search for available users and after
  list of users been generated add **"IIS_IUSRS"** then OK.
- Give **IIS_IUSRS** permissions to modify.
- Done.